# Observer on class Mage_Core_Model_App end in function run

Tags: magento-1.8, php, event-observer

Look `app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php`

```
public function run($params)
    {
        $options = isset($params['options']) ? $params['options'] : array();
        $this->baseInit($options);
        Mage::register('application_params', $params);

        if ($this->_cache->processRequest()) {
            $this->getResponse()->sendResponse();
        } else {
            $this->_initModules();
            $this->loadAreaPart(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_GLOBAL, Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::PART_EVENTS);

            if ($this->_config->isLocalConfigLoaded()) {
                $scopeCode = isset($params['scope_code']) ? $params['scope_code'] : '';
                $scopeType = isset($params['scope_type']) ? $params['scope_type'] : 'store';
                $this->_initCurrentStore($scopeCode, $scopeType);
                $this->_initRequest();
                Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllDataUpdates();
            }

            $this->getFrontController()->dispatch();
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

I know that to create an event / observer I need to do the following:

```
<events>
  <EVENT_TO_HOOK>
    <observers>
      <module>
        <type>singleton</type>
        <class>company_module_model_observer</class>
        <method>methodToCall</method>
      </module>
    </observers>
  </EVENT_TO_HOOK>     
</events>
```

but i dont know how to catch the event of the `run` function of the class `Mage_Core_Model_App`

what is the name of the event in order to observe this function?

Comment: If all that `Mage::run()` will do is dispatch front controller, why not observe the predispatch??

Comment: You sure you want to "observe" this? Wouldn't you achieve the same by overriding the run method of Mage_Core_Model_App and putting parent::run() followed by your custom code that you would handle in the observer?

Comment: I wanted to make a module to get data of `getModelInstance`, `getNodeClassInstance` and `getResourceModelInstance` of the class `Mage_Core_Model_Config` , any idea how I can do this

Comment: What do you exactly mean saying  _I wanted to make a module to get data of getModelInstance, getNodeClassInstance and getResourceModelInstance of the class Mage_Core_Model_Config_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to catch the start or end of the `Mage_Core_Model_App::run` action.
And there is no way to extend the `Mage_Core_Model_App` class because it is instantiated using `new`.
You can copy the class in `local` codepool and do your magic there.
Or you can use the events available in the other methods. The first one dispatched I think it is `controller_front_init_before`.